# Loss of SIP Header Values ​on Transfer

Tags: asterisk, sip

Closed. This question is not about programming or software development. It is not currently accepting answers.
This question does not appear to be about a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or software tools primarily used by programmers. You can edit the question so it's on-topic or see if it can be answered on another Stack Exchange site, but be sure to read the on-topic page for a site before posting there.

Closed 6 hours ago.

I’m new to Asterisk. I’m facing a problem and I’ve been struggling with it for a few days.

I have two asterisk servers. Let’s assume their names are ast182 and ast 189. I add the incoming information on the ast189 machine to the sipheader with

```
same => n,Set(PJSIP_HEADER(add,${VAR_NAME})=${VAR_VALUE})
```

and send it to the transfer context to the ast182 machine. Here I direct the incoming call to the field trunk. This is how I do it.

ast182

```
[transfer]
exten => _X.,1,NoOp(Transfer Request Incoming for Exten:  ${EXTEN})
same => n,Dial(PJSIP/${EXTEN}@saha)
same => n,Hangup()
pjsip.conf on ast182

[saha]
type=endpoint
transport=transport-tcp
context=saha_inbound
disallow=all
allow=alaw

aors=saha_aors

[saha_aors]
type=aor
contact=sip:IPsaha:5060
```

When I open pjsip logger with this asterisk -rx "pjsip set logger on" the values ​​I set in the header come from ast189. Example log:

> Received SIP request (1248 bytes) from UDP:IPast189:5062 —> INVITE
> sip:48196@IPast182:5062 SIP/2.0 Via: SIP/2.0/UDP
> IPast189:5062;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPj45739d6f-16bd-472d-8321-f1aebe6fe5a5
> From: sip:1476329@IPast189;tag=10dfd5a3-962c-472d-92bd-7bdb2d447cda
> To: sip:48196@IPast182 Contact: sip:asterisk@IPast189:5062 Call-ID:
> 6f09bed2-4220-4255-aec7-ddb53487d03c CSeq: 23812 INVITE Allow:
> OPTIONS, REGISTER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, INVITE, ACK, BYE,
> CANCEL, UPDATE, PRACK, MESSAGE, REFER Supported: 100rel, timer,
> replaces, norefersub, histinfo Session-Expires: 1800 Min-SE: 90
> cti_VdnLabel: TREDAS_OPERATOR cti_CallDirection: 1 cti_ContractNumber:
> 0021164311 cti_IvrCallEndTime: 2024-02-13 22:41:46.015
> cti_IvrCallStartTime: 2024-02-13 22:41:06.298 cti_CallAni: 1476329
> cti_CallId: s200iap01-1707853265.521941 cti_TransferVDN: 48196
> cti_CallStartTime: 2024-02-13 22:41:03.298 cti_IvrButton: 5
> Max-Forwards: 70 User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 16.28.0 Content-Type:
> application/sdp Content-Length: 239

However, it does not send any parameters when sending to the saha trunk.

> Transmitting SIP request (939 bytes) to TCP:IPsaha:5060 —> INVITE
> sip:48196@IPsaha:5060 SIP/2.0 Via: SIP/2.0/TCP
> IPast182:5060;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPja0ddd4b6-3f04-440a-baf7-1947dfcdf1c9;alias
> From: sip:1476329@IPast182;tag=f7b5939b-b81d-4077-8442-7d1c8f3c1c01
> To: sip:48196@IPsaha Contact: sip:asterisk@IPast182:5060;transport=TCP
> Call-ID: b50e7040-24fe-4833-8b08-f28f2499a6eb CSeq: 29468 INVITE
> Allow: OPTIONS, REGISTER, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, INVITE, ACK,
> BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, PRACK, MESSAGE, REFER Supported: 100rel, timer,
> replaces, norefersub, histinfo Session-Expires: 1800 Min-SE: 90
> Max-Forwards: 70 User-Agent: Asterisk PBX 16.28.0 Content-Type:
> application/sdp Content-Length: 241
>
> v=0 o=- 1507201859 1507201859 IN IP4 IPast182 s=Asterisk c=IN IP4
> IPast182 t=0 0 m=audio 16172 RTP/AVP 8 101 a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
> a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000 a=fmtp:101 0-16 a=ptime:20
> a=maxptime:150 a=sendrecv

The parts of logs is above

The call is transferred, but the values ​​added to the header are not transferred. I appreciate any help. Thanks!